# Can I build an optimization surface after running the heuristic algorithm

Tags: r, optimization

Actually the whole question is in the title.
Can I somehow restore and build an optimization surface after optimization with a heuristic algorithm ...

Probably, you must first fill / interpolate those values ​​that the algorithm did not calculate in the fitness function, and then reduce the dimension

I'm wondering if there are packages that do this

Comment: Do you really expect to able to reconstruct the entire optimization surface from some set of points ?

Comment: I'm just wondering if there is such a technology, also somewhere on the Internet I saw a drawing of the optimization surface of a neural network

Comment: It is of course possible to draw such a thing by *evaluating* the loss function at many points, which is clearly highly computationally intensive when the dimensionality is not small. You can look here https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.09913 for an example

Comment: thanks, but is there such a thing for R?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with R so I can't tell

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about after as you may have very few non-representative points, especially if your optimizer solved your problem quickly (which one would expect from a heuristic algorithm), and these points may be highly correlated. You will probably have to solve this separately from your optimization, good news is such algorithms already exist, such as the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, which is used in Bayesian statistics to sample from a posterior distribution - or in your case given an objective function.

The algorithm itself is not very complicated, you can write it in a couple lines of code, see [Implementing a Metropolis Hastings Algorithm in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72104/implementing-a-metropolis-hastings-algorithm-in-r) for some references.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Because of my education, it is difficult for me to understand what is written in the links that you gave. I would be very grateful if you could give an example in R how to restore an optimization surface using the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm